# trouble in read tab delimited file R

Tags: r

I am trying to read a tab delimited file that looks like this:
[image]

I am using the read.table for this propose but I am not able to read the file.

```
table<- read.table("/Users/Desktop/R-test/HumanHT-12_V4_0_R2_15002873_B.txt",
                   header =FALSE, sep = "\t", 
                   comment.char="#", check.names=FALSE)
```

When I run the code I have this error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 2 elements
```

What am I doing wrong while reading the table? 
I am not so familiarized with R, so any help would be really useful.

Comment: try adding `skip=9` to ignore the first few lines that don't belong to the table

Comment: But I need to read all the information in the file

Comment: then read the first few lines (or all of it) with `scan()` or `readLines()`, and the rest with `read.table`.

Comment: `read.table` reads data into a data frame, which is a structured data object: a fixed number of data columns. The forst 9 lines of your file do not fit that data frame structure, and do not belong in the data frame with the rest of the data. Hence @bapstiste's excellent advice,

Comment: I am using this code now: con<-file("/Users/bioinfo/Desktop/R-test/HumanHT-12_V4_0_R2_15002873_B.txt","rt")

fist8<-readLines(con,8) 
table<- read.table(con,header =FALSE, skip=8,sep = "\t", comment.char="", check.names=FALSE)                                                   and it still does not work, I have this error now: Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 104 did not have 28 elements

Comment: Note that `read.delim` sets `fill = TRUE`. You will probably find that setting `fill = TRUE` in your current code would eliminate the latest error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am very familiar with this type of file: It is a GEO platform data for Microarray analysis.
As baptiste proposed above, the best way is to skip the first few lines by `skip=9`. You may replace `read.table(...,sep="\t")` with just `read.delim(...)`. Then you will have your table with suitable column names - please note that the column names should be in the 1st line.

Then if you are really interested in the first 9 lines you may read them by `readLines(...)` command and paste the data to your table by acting like this:

```
foo = read.delim(...)
bar = readLines(...)
baz = list(foo, bar)
```